# Tips for Golfing in Vyxal 3

Tags: tips, vyxal

*The reason for this question is because I made a [deadlineless bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26136/78850) and I need a tips question to link in the bounty*

Vyxal 3 is the third major version of the Vyxal golfing language. As it is significantly different to Vyxal 2, the tips there don't apply.

Therefore, what tips and tricks do you have for golfing in Vyxal 3? Avoid giving obvious
help like "remove whitespace", "limit variable usage", "remove comments" and "don't pad your program with 20000 among us characters".

One tip per answer please.

Literate mode golfing tips are also welcome.

Comment: 

Comment: I would suggest removing whitespace, limiting variable usage, removing comments, and not padding your program with 20000 among us characters. They're all very helpful tips.

Answer (score 5):

## Compress Strings and Numbers

Like Vyxal 2 before it, Vyxal 3 has dictionary string compression and base-based compression. However, in Vyxal 3, dictionary strings use Jelly's sss and base-based compression uses base-252 instead of base-255.

Dictionary compression works on all strings, base string compression only works on strings of lowercase alphabet + space (`[a-z ]`), base number compression only works on positive numbers.

To compress a string using dictionary compression:

```
"Some string" #C
```

To compress a string using base compression:

```
"some lowercase string" #c
```

To compress a number using base compression:

```
69420 #c
```

### Examples

| Original Value | Dictionary Compressed | Base Compressed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `"hello world"` | `"Ṙ=?”` | `"ᶠ»_Ṃ†ᵘy„` |
| `"Hello, World!"` | `"Ḍᵗ{w<ᵏ”` | NA |
| `69420` | NA | `"ᵇᵡy“` |

Comment: How about compressing a list of strings? A list of numbers?